# E/launcher - Error: TSError: Unable to Compile Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

**Hey guys, I am facing following problem:**

My Project is built on Angular4 with typescript, e2e testing with protractor & karma. But since a few days I keep getting following error:

```
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/protractor/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (
6054)
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/q/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.
d.ts'. (6054)
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/source-map/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (
6054)
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/tapable/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (605
4)
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/tslib/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)

File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/uglify-js/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6
054)
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only support
ed extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File 'D:/myproject/node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx',
 '.d.ts'. (6054)
    at getOutput (D:\myproject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:300:15)
    at D:\myproject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:330:16
    at Object.compile (D:\myproject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:489:17)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\myproject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:382:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (D:\myproject\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:385:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
[23:41:57] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

As I understand the error message, the typscript loader tries to transpile non-ts files. For sure I have searched the whole internet before posting my question, and it looks like something with the @types within my [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) is not working properly.

I have checked the documentation for @types and tsconfig and related issues on github, but I think it's not behaving correctly here. The Docs state that,

> only files with supported extensions are included (e.g. .ts, .tsx, and
>   .d.ts by default with .js and .jsx if allowJs is set to true).

Then why is it trying to include all the .json files?

---

> **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Detailed Information about myproject:

> node v7.4.0
>
> npm  v4.1.2
>
> typescript@2.3.4
>
> protractor@5.1.2

```
├── src/
│   ├── custom-typings.d.ts
├── node_modules/
│   ├── @types
│   |   ├── hammerjs
│   |   |   ├── index.d.ts
│   |   |   ├── package.json
│   |   |   ├── README.md
│   |   |   ├── types-metadata.json
│   |   ├── jasmine
│   |   |   ├── index.d.ts
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── node
│   |   |   ├── index.d.ts
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── source-map
│   |   |   ├── index.d.ts
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── uglify-js
│   |   |   ├── index.d.ts
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── webpack
│   |   |   ├── index.d.ts
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── ...
│   └── (@agm, @angular, ...)
└── package.json
```

**What I have already tried:**

- removing exclude block, as it contains same as default value:

> The "exclude" property defaults to excluding the node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages and  directories when not specified.

- setting option "allowJs: true", resulted in missing loader for files (not an appropriate solution)
- removing typeRoots to use default settings, resulted in same error

How can I solve this, to load only appropriate .ts files?
Thanks in advance for any help!

- adding `"include": [
  "src/**/*"
  ]` or `"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts"
  ]` - resulted in the same error

---

additional resources:

- [installed packages and versions](https://pastebin.com/Hx8Ddf2V)

Comment: Maybe use `include` to only include your project and TS files?

Comment: @AndrewLi As I understood [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) and the fact I didn't define `files` or `include` it already should only include all .ts files of my project. Apart from that, I tried to set `"include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],` which resulted in the same error - still trying to include .json files